# Как разработать журальное приложение для киоска?

Tags: ios, pdf

Мало информации о разработке журнальных приложений для киоска под iOS (или у меня вектор поиска кривой). Дайте побольше ссылок по этой теме.

Меня интересуют следующие вопросы:

1. В каком формате загружаются журналы?
2. Можно ли загружать журналы в PDF?
3. Чем отличается киоск-приложение от обычного приложения?
4. Как приложение попадает в киоск?
5. Как организована платная подписка?

Comment: Мне кажется что у киоска нету подписки вообще. Просто платные операции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Журнал может быть просто приложением с разными выпусками, например 3D-активный обзор последних технологий. Это будет одно приложение, информирующее юзера, в своей форме о чем-то, но с разными выпусками.
2. Да.
3. http://www.apperplace.com/difference-newsstand-home-screen-apps/
4. Добавьте в info проекта "Application presents content in Newsstand" со значением "YES", и приложение станет появляться только в киоске.
5. Тут ничего не подскажу...